# Why is docker build prefixing my copy path with a temp directory?

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

Here is the DockerFile.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

And here is the error.

```
Error
Building a.enterpriseextservices
Service 'a.enterpriseextservices' failed to build: COPY failed: 
GetFileAttributesEx \\?\C:\Users\jesmiller-AM\AppData\Local\Temp\docker-
builder587295999\obj\Docker\publish: The system cannot find the file specified..

For more troubleshooting information, go to 
http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting    docker-compose  C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets  349
```

I have published the project to the obj/Docker/publish folder.
Here is my docker-compose file. I used the docker-compose up command from the folder where the docker-compose.yml file is located.

```
version: '3'

services:
  a.web.familyconnection:
    image: a.web.familyconnection
    build:
      context: .\FamilyConnection
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  b.enterpriseextservices:
    image: b.enterpriseextservices
    build:
      context: .\Framework\b.EnterpriseExtServices
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: What command arguments are you using to build? I haven't seen the ${} interpolation syntax before, is that some kind of plugin? That error message looks similar to errors I've seen on COPY before which isa missing file (as your error states). Perhaps your path is being interpolated incorrectly?

Comment: The problem is this path: \\?\C:\Users\jesmiller-AM\AppData\Local\Temp\docker-
builder587295999\. I did not put that in there, it is auto generated each time, and it is different each time. And I do not know where it is getting that path from.

Comment: It looks like you're using docker compose as well. If so, can you post your compose file & the command you're using? (build or run, and any args)

Comment: Edited the original post to include the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: The variable path is a temporary folder on the server that is populated with your build context. Docker builds on the server, not the client, and they may not always be the same machine. Check the case on your directory names.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turned out I made a silly mistake. I added the following to my .dockerignore file, just out of habit when setting up a new project:

```
bin
obj
.vs
.git
```

Then I tried running this in my Dockerfile

```
COPY ./bin/publish/ .
```

Docker gave the strange tmp path error, because it was falling back to that path since I told it to ignore my /bin folder. Once I copied to a different publish path (not bin), the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your path to the folders, or where you've published your code at may be incorrect. The project should be published in the `obj/Docker/publish` folder inside of the respective folders defined by `context`

Using an example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  foo:
    build: ./foo
  bar:
    build: ./bar
```

And `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jaydorsey/ruby-2.4.1

COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

And a tree structure like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── bar
│   └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── foo
│   └── Dockerfile
└── obj
    └── Docker
        └── publish
```

When I run `docker-compose build` I get the following error

```
Building foo
Step 1/2 : FROM jaydorsey/ruby-2.4.1
 ---> b79899b232f6
Step 2/2 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ERROR: Service 'foo' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder186649811/obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory
```

This isn't identical to yours, since I'm running macOS, but very similar. You'll note the temporary file location (which is an internal Docker artifact of how it's copying files around) and the similarity in the `docker-build<randomstring>` path

However, if I create the `obj/Docker/publish` folders underneath each respective subfolder (`context`), the `docker-compose build` command works fine.

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── bar
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── obj
│       └── Docker
│           └── publish
├── docker-compose.yml
├── foo
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── obj
│       └── Docker
│           └── publish
└── obj
    └── Docker
        └── publish
```

Please check that the folder you've published exists under the contexts as noted, and not in the root.

I still believe this is a path issue as noted in the error message. I hope this provides some context that helps you debug the root cause.

Can you please confirm your file & folder layout? I'm fairly certain it's path related because of the error message. I haven't done any Docker for Windows work either but I'd also double-check your default path using the correct slash (forward vs backward)

Comment: Those folder exist exactly where they should in relation to the project. I agree it is a path issue but I do not know what is causing it as I am set up exactly how EVERY tutorial and help site has said to do it and it is still not working. If I build it from inside visual studio with only one project referenced in the docker-compose file it works. The problem happens when I want to reference a project from another solution in the docker compose file it breaks in Visual studio, or if I run docker-compose up outside of visual studio it breaks as well.

Comment: @JesseMiller does the obj/Docker/publish folder exist under both the FamilyConnection and Framework\b.EnterpriseExtServices folders?

Comment: Yes it does. I have already published the files to that folder in both cases.

Comment: @JesseMiller The only other thing I can think to check is a) Double-check your slashes (I don't know how compose/Dockerfile deals with forward/backward) b) try removing the interpolation from the COPY command in the Dockerfile; c) Make sure you're not using shortcuts or symlinks; d) Try each service individually, to see if they build in isolation; e) Check Docker issues to see if there is a problem with the Windows Docker stuff & paths; f) Try the edge channel Docker and see if that resolves the issue (you'll lose all existing images and containers when you switch)